# Developing Windows 8 / Metro Apps Offline

Tags: microsoft-metro, offline

Are there any alternate ways to develop Metro/Windows 8 style apps without obtaining a Windows 8 developer license?

Our department wants to explore the development of corporate, strictly in house, applications for our upcoming Windows 8 deployment next year.

There is no ability to fetch a license offline (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974578.aspx and http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762946/cannot-request-offline-developer-license-for-visual-studio-2012-windows-store-app).

Without an internet connection you can’t obtain the Windows 8 developer license from VS2012, and I can’t find any work around.

Does anybody have a work around to enable development of Windows 8 apps without requiring an internet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hot fix available for this.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2871280

Answer (score 3):

It was quite frustrating for me that I will never be able to create win8 apps since my developer machine will always be off-line. So I have created a petition to Microsoft to provide a means to obtain a license off-line.

If you are reading this and also want to see a means of obtaining a Windows 8 developer license off-line, please drop your vote here:

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3313641-provide-a-way-to-obtain-a-windows-8-developer-lice

Comment: Totally agree - very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are required to renew this developer's licence every month, so it's not really a one time thing.

Answer (score 0):

While you need an internet connection to initially obtain a licence, once you have done this, you can develop applications entirely offline. This is not an unusual model! Quite a lot of applications require a one-time registration initially.

Comment: Agreed - But the gotcha is there doesn't appear to be a way to get the license in the first place without going on the internet.  In secure environments, once a computer has been on the internet it is considered extremely dangerous and is disposed.   I can't find a way to generate a license file and then import it electronically without the machine being internet connected.

Comment: Wow - that is a tricky one. How do you develop in there secure environments ... without StackOveflow! impossible ;-)